# Coating/skin on Quorn Sausage - is it edible?

Tags: sausages, skin

I bought some frozen Quorn Hot Dogs (Frankfurter style). After boiling some there was a transparent, filmy outer skin/coating that came off when I was cutting them. It felt plastic/rubber/paper-like but I wasn't able to distinguish it properly. I had a look at some of the frozen ones in the pack and was able to peel the skin off some of them but not with others.

There is no mention of this skin on the package or in the ingredients. I searched online but only found a few posts/comments mentioning the skin peeling off the sausage.

My question is, what is this coating and is it edible?

Here's what the packaging looks like if anyone else wants to check: http://www.ocado.com/productImages/840/84090011_0_640x640.jpg?identifier=a6c3b6a50e16995b0ceea7cecdca4490

Comment: I don't know this specific product, but I'll lean towards not edible. 1) I've never seen a frankfurter with an edible skin, and 2) your picture says meat-free, and edible skins are made from animal guts.

Comment: There exist [edible vegan sausage casings](http://www.meatprocessingproducts.com/27801.html), but I don't know how common they are.  I would suspect that they'd be used for fresh sausages, as for cooked sausages they use an inedible casing, then strip it off between cooking & packaging.

Comment: If it wasn't edible, I would really, _really_ hope there would be a prominent warning on the package, or at least instructions to remove it before/after cooking.

Comment: It's interesting that I can find from [some product information sites](http://www.sainsburys.co.uk/webapp/wcs/stores/servlet/gb/groceries/quorn-hot-dogs-270g?langId=44&storeId=10151&krypto=R1iRgP6tlfxTm6rTLFLu2piee1FPXRo8Q0oRBi4nJHhbtK%2BPFlF%2BUxE0DTCee457MgeMC52slRrj%0AvhAgIhKnnPVcBOM4cngydQnvT%2BC9U3OJZm0%2FVsvf8WJC2CJbqBw7&ddkey=http:gb/groceries/quorn-hot-dogs-270g) that the casing ingredients are "Casing (Stabiliser: Sodium Alginate; Cellulose, Modified Starch)", but I can't find that information from the actual Quorn website.

Answer (score 3):

They are edible I eat them all the time they are the same ones on the regular Quorn sausages.
I prefer to microwave mine though it keeps the skin on and cooks quicker, also it keeps in more of the flavour.